# TDD causes unnecessary objects in Cocoa development

Tags: cocoa, tdd

I'm trying to do more test driven development but I'm conflicted on the objects it forces to be added to my code.  Specifically I have two text fields in my storyboard, and I'm binding their *values* to a variable in the view controller.  Works great.

If I use TDD for this, though, I have to link an @IBOutlet for each text field for the sole purpose of allowing the unit test to examine the binding of that text field.

When I'm looking through the code much later, I'll notice that the outlet is never accessed and delete it, and then run the tests and suddenly they fail because that useless linked variable is gone.

Is there a better way to handle the validation that the text field is linked to the variable?

I know it doesn't break anything to have that outlet defined, but suddenly I have multiple variables created that not only don't I truly need for the code, but they have to be non-private variables as well, which suddenly exposes an implementation detail to other classes in the project that shouldn't be using that variable.

Comment: If you don't need the outlet for the code, you don't need it for the test, I think. How does the app works? Bindings?

Comment: Yes, bindings.   In the test class, if I don't have an outlet, how do I test that the binding is set then?